# How to extract path from a variable with additional characters in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to extract `/temp/bin/usr/` from a variable

```
$path  = /temp/bin/usr/...
```

using perl.
Can someone help me with that ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  If so, please include your code.

Comment: Is that the full path or part of the file path? `/temp/bin/usr/somedir/dir3/file.txt`, or `/temp/bin/usr/file.txt`? There's a difference.

Comment: its simply /temp/bin/usr/... and i need to remove those dots

Comment: @aadi That might have been a good thing to be more specific about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to remove those '..' in the end there're many ways.

For example:

1)

```
my $str="/temp/bin/usr/..."; 
($str) =~ s/\.+$//; 
print $str;
```

2)

```
my $str="/temp/bin/usr/..."; 
$str = substr($str, 0, index($str, "."));
print $str;
```

3)

```
my $str="/temp/bin/usr/..."; 
$str = (split /\./, $str)[0];
print $str;
```

And there're many more!

Comment: `split` and `index` will fail for paths such as `/foo/.bar/...`.

Comment: agree, but OP didn't mention the pattern may vary.

Answer (score 3):

Use `File::Basename`. It is a core module in Perl version 5. From [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aBasename):

```
use File::Basename;

($name,$path,$suffix) = fileparse($fullname, @suffixlist);
$name = fileparse($fullname, @suffixlist);

$basename = basename($fullname, @suffixlist);
$dirname  = dirname($fullname);
```

It sounds like `dirname($path)` is what you are after.

You may also simply use a regex

```
$path =~ s/\.+$//;
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract part of a path, for example, the first three directories, one way is to use the method `splitdir` of the module `File::Spec`, like:

```
printf "%s\n", join q|/|, (File::Spec->splitdir( $path ))[0..3];
```

If you want to remove those dots, use a regular expression that matches them after last slash, like:

```
$path =~ s|(/)\.+\s*$|$1|;
```

Comment: `0 .. 2` for three elements. Good solution, though, I will reference it in my answer.

Comment: My mistake, the OP meant something else.. I will not reference it. Still a good answer.

Comment: @TLP: I wasn't sure either, so I added two different ways to accomplish a task like that. I think that the OP won't have much problem to solve his issue due to the answers he got.